# How to position a div into the gap created by two other divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a fluid layout but I can't seem to position the purple/black div in the correct spot. How do I get the div to move upward so that it can fill the space that is created by the previous divs. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="square-one"></div>
    <div class="square-two"></div>
    <div class="square-three"></div>
    <div class="square-four"></div>
    <div class="square-five"></div>
    <div class="square-six"></div>
    <div class="container-three"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.square-one {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.square-two {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #63D6C3;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.square-three {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #F86060;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.square-four {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.square-five {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #FBFAED;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.square-six {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #061D33;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

`This is what I get: 
[image]

This is what I want
[image]

Comment: Love the colors.  What you seem to be needing is a layout similar to what the masonry plugin creates.  You may not be able to achieve this without the use of javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `.square-three` to `float: right;`:

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
}
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
border: 1px solid grey;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.square-one {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.square-two {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #63D6C3;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.square-three {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #F86060;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.square-four {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.square-five {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #FBFAED;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.square-six {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #061D33;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="square-one">1</div>
    <div class="square-two">2</div>
    <div class="square-three">3</div>
    <div class="square-four">4</div>
    <div class="square-five">5</div>
    <div class="square-six">6</div>
    <div class="container-three">x</div>
</div>
```

The space between the DIVs could be done with margins (which you'd have to consider when setting the DIV widths, using `calc(width_in_percent - sum_of_margins)`, but you didn't add any yourself, so I also didn't do it.